# Use a view page as child page in every content drupal 7

Tags: views

I created a content type *libro* and a content type *capitolo*. In type *capitolo* there's an entity reference to *libro*.
I would like to create a child page `/capitoli` so that in

> example.com/A/capitoli

all type *capitolo* linked with *libro* A are shown, in

> example.com/B/capitoli

all type *capitolo* linked with *libro* B are shown

and so on for every *libro*.

I've already prepared a view page that shows all capitoli taken from contextual filter nid, taking it from URL, even if probably it's not the right way to approach this. I'm using Drupal 7.
Sorry for my bad English and for the bad description of the problem

---First Edit---

Ok i modified url alias so that now a libro1 object has as url *www.example.com/libro/libro1*, but it is still not working. I post here how i did my view:

Fields
Content:title(Capitolo)

Filter criteria
Contenuto: Pubblished (Yes)
Contenuto: Type (= Capitolo)

Path : /libro/%/capitoli

Contextual filters
(Content entity referenced from field_libro) File Usage: Entity type (as suggested in answers)

I even tried to add a relatioship

Relationships
Entity Reference: Libro

and use that in the contextual filter, but it is still not working.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it was wrong. Apparently you can only use entity id as a contextual filter. Thefore, since it's an id and not a name it won't work with the % since the % is the name of the book.

Comment: @NoSssweat I really don't know how i could reach the libro id unfortunately. Thanks anyway

Comment: I believe the only way would be to use the Display Suite module or the Panels module in order to pass the entity id to the view. I might get back to you on this one later.